# Are these equiv? $\cot^{-1}(-x) = -\cot^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse

$-\cot(y)=x$

Let's say you want to put this in terms of y...

$\cot(y)=-x$

$y = \cot^{-1}(-x)$

===================

Is this also valid ?

$-\cot(y)=x$

$y = -\cot^{-1}(x)$

## If yes, how exactly does one arrive that that result?

In other words, are these equivalent?

$\cot^{-1}(-x) = -\cot^{-1}(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and yes.

Recall that when you take the inverse, you need to take the inverse on both sides. So what you've actually done is $$-cot(y)=x$$ $$cot^{-1}(-cot(y))=cot^{-1}(x)$$
which is not equivalent to $y = -cot^{-1}(x)$.

However, it is true that $cot^{-1}(x)$ is an odd function.

Comment: So, you just happen to get lucky in this example, and get away with the 2nd method which is really just a mistake?

Comment: Yes. You can try for yourself that this is most definitely not the case if you consider the function $sec$.

Comment: Ok, the conclusion is that $cot^{-1}(-cot(y)) \ne$ $cot^{-1}(cot(y))$

Comment: You mean $cot^{-1}(-cot(y)) \ne -cot^{-1}(cot(y))?$

Answer (score 2):

I get this... So they differ by $\pi$...

[image: T2]

[image: T1]

So, the answer depends on your definition of $\mathrm{arccot}$.

**added**
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) we can define $y = \mathrm{arccot}(x)$ to mean: $x = \cot y$ and $0 < y < \pi$.  The advantage is that it is a continuous function.  And $\mathrm{arccot}\; x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x$

Comment: What definition of $arccot$ is used here? Since at $x=0$ these functions are discontinuous.